# Will talking to the two secruity guards in the third mission disqualify me from getting the Ghost experience bonus?

Tags: deus-ex-human-revolution

During the third mission, at FEMA, it's possible to come across these security guards:

[image]

I assume if they go hostile it will disqualify me for it, but what if I bluff my way out of it? Will I still  be disqualified from the Ghost experience bonus?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

No, you won't be disqualified from the "ghost" bonus. But you will need to hack the terminal to the door which they are standing next to. Hacking after bluffing will turn them hostile and then you WILL lose your ghost bonus.

So my advice is to bluff and perform a silent take down taking them out at once, and then hack the terminal.

Comment: I concur. Ghost only applies if you are seen by a "hostile" character that will shoot on sight/sound an alarm if they see you.

Comment: Do you have anything to back-up your answer, or are you just guessing?

Comment: On my play through I bluffed, and then used the double takedown to wipe them both out and I still got ghost.